STM32F4 ADC square wave distortion
I'm building what is essentially a signal recorder based on STM32F401CCU6 ("black pill" board) and the waveform as evaluated by the ADC contains strange artifacts compared to the scope plot measuredat the ADC input.
Apologies for the crude schematic made in draw.io - it's a basic transimpedance amplifier using an MCP6002:

Here's the voltage plot of the signal at the MCU's ADC input - a fairly clean pulse: 
Here's the signal as decoded by the ADC (ignore the timing, it's incorrect). Note the two "protrusions" at the beginning and the end of the pulse shelf, as if the rising edge would "swing" past the end (??)

I'm using the standard ADC setup - ADC1, 12 bit (same on 8 bit), 100 kHz rate, PCLK2/6,
with DMA transfer.
I've also tried the ADC accuracy tricks from ST AN4073 with no noticeable effect

Your scope says that the max voltage level is 4.64v. Surely that's well above what you can safely feed into your STM32's ADC? It probably only has a 3.3v supply ...
